# Pool size isn't spawning enough processes

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, passenger, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running `Passenger with Ruby 2.5 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.9.3` and I am trying to pass arguments via command line to increase `--min-instances` & `--max-pool-size`

the code involved in doing this is the following line

```
GENERALOPTS="-p $EB_HTTP_PORT --pid-file $EB_APP_PID_DIR/passenger.pid --min-instances=${PASSENGER_MIN_POOL_SIZE:-6} --max-pool-size=${PASSENGER_MAX_POOL_SIZE:-6}"
```

My environment variable values for `PASSENGER_MIN_POOL_SIZE` & `PASSENGER_MAX_POOL_SIZE` are set to `50`.

The problem i am facing is it will only spawn 36 processes instead of 50 for some reason. what am i doing wrong?

Here is my full config file

```
files:
  "/tmp/passenger.config":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      #
      # chkconfig: 2345 80 20
      # description: Passenger
      #

      EB_HTTP_PORT=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k http_port)
      EB_APP_USER=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_user)
      EB_APP_DEPLOY_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_deploy_dir)
      EB_APP_PID_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_pid_dir)
      EB_APP_LOG_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_log_dir)
      EB_SCRIPT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k script_dir)
      EB_SUPPORT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k support_dir)
      EB_NGINX_VERSION=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k nginx_version)

      . $EB_SUPPORT_DIR/envvars
      . $EB_SCRIPT_DIR/use-app-ruby.sh

      if [ -f /etc/elasticbeanstalk/set-ulimit.sh ]; then
        . /etc/elasticbeanstalk/set-ulimit.sh
      fi

      # fixes http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=614
      export HOME=/tmp
      export PASSENGER_DOWNLOAD_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0

      if [ -d /etc/healthd ]; then
          STARTOPTS="--nginx-version $EB_NGINX_VERSION --nginx-config-template $EB_SUPPORT_DIR/conf/nginx_config_healthd.erb"
      else
          STARTOPTS="--nginx-version $EB_NGINX_VERSION --nginx-config-template $EB_SUPPORT_DIR/conf/nginx_config.erb"
      fi

      ENV_STAGE=${RACK_ENV:-$RAILS_ENV}    # Read from $RAILS_ENV if $RACK_ENV is empty
      if [ ${ENV_STAGE,,} = "production" ]; then    # Convert $ENV_STAGE to lower case and compare to "production"
        # Disable passenger friendly page for production stage
        STARTOPTS="$STARTOPTS --no-friendly-error-pages"
      fi

      GENERALOPTS="-p $EB_HTTP_PORT --pid-file $EB_APP_PID_DIR/passenger.pid --min-instances=${PASSENGER_MIN_POOL_SIZE:-6} --max-pool-size=${PASSENGER_MAX_POOL_SIZE:-6}"

      function start() {
        touch $EB_APP_LOG_DIR/passenger.log

        if [ -d /etc/healthd ]; then
          mkdir -p $EB_APP_LOG_DIR/healthd
          chown -R $EB_APP_USER:$EB_APP_USER $EB_APP_LOG_DIR/healthd
        fi

        chown $EB_APP_USER:$EB_APP_USER \
          $EB_APP_LOG_DIR/passenger.log
        passenger start $EB_APP_DEPLOY_DIR $STARTOPTS $GENERALOPTS \
          -d -e ${RACK_ENV:-$RAILS_ENV} --user $EB_APP_USER \
          --log-file $EB_APP_LOG_DIR/passenger.log
      }

      function stop() {
        passenger stop $GENERALOPTS
      }

      function status() {
        passenger status $GENERALOPTS
      }

      case "$1" in
        start)
          start
          ;;
        stop)
          stop
          ;;
        status)
          status
          ;;
        restart|graceful)
          stop
          start
          ;;
        reload)
          su -s /bin/bash -c "touch $EB_APP_DEPLOY_DIR/tmp/restart.txt" $EB_APP_USER
          ;;
        *)
          echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|reload|status}"
          exit 1
          ;;
      esac

      exit 0

container_commands:
  01_config_passenger:
    command: "cp /tmp/passenger.config /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/passenger"
```

Comment: Is this the professional version for Passenger? If not, you'll only use processes for concurrency, which is a shame, since both Puma and iodine support the hybrid approach where both threads and workers are used (and they're free).

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and configuration but it seems `--max-pool-size` is not an available option for nor `/etc/init.d/passenger stop` nor `/etc/init.d/passenger restart` because I was getting

[image]

So I moved `--max-pool-size` from `$GENERALOPTS` to `start` command only. You should have something like

```
(...)
passenger start $EB_APP_DEPLOY_DIR $STARTOPTS $GENERALOPTS \
 --min-instances=${PASSENGER_MIN_POOL_SIZE:-6} \
 --max-pool-size=${PASSENGER_MAX_POOL_SIZE:-6} \
 -d -e ${RACK_ENV:-$RAILS_ENV} --user $EB_APP_USER \
(...)
```

And that worked to me as a charm!